# Enforce same type for generic function (best practice)

Tags: java, generics, methods

I have a generic function which recieves two arguments which should be of the same type.

Until now the function looked like this:

```
void <T> copyTo1(Class<T> type, T destination, T source) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This works fine, but I think it's not the right way to achieve my goal since type won't be used in the function. So I looked for another solution and came up with this:

```
void <T, S extends T> copyTo2(T destination, S source) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

The kind of calls these two functions allow look like this:

```
copyTo1(Object.class, new Object(), new Object()); // Okay
copyTo1(Object.class, new Object(), new String()); // Okay
copyTo1(Object.class, new String(), new Object()); // Okay
copyTo1(String.class, new String(), new String()); // Okay
copyTo1(String.class, new String(), new Date()); // Not okay

copyTo2(new Object(), new Object()); // Okay
copyTo2(new Object(), new String()); // Okay
copyTo2(new String(), new Object()); // Not okay
copyTo2(new String(), new Date()); // Not okay
```

The second alternative is more restrictive, which is perfectly fine for me.

Now the question is: Which approach should be prefered? Or is there another one I didn't see?

Many thanks in advance.

---

*Just for the record: I know that I can define and use the function like this ...*

```
void <T> copyTo(T destination, T source) {
    // Do stuff
}

...

this.<String> copyTo(new String(), new String());
```

*But I want the user to instantly see when the operation he is trying isn't allowed. Which isn't the case when he ommits the definition of the type.*

Comment: This is IMO not about best practice, but about requirement. What kind of relation would you want between the `destination` and `source`, use type parameters accordingly.

Comment: @RohitJain I agree, choose whichever one suits best. If the more restrictive one works, go for it!

Comment: I forgot to mention that `type` would be unused in the concrete implementation.

Comment: I would prefer the second option, but it is ultimately a matter of the concrete requirements.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I opted for the second version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what exactly does "should be of the same type" mean? All references in Java are instances of `Object`, so by definition they are always "of the same type". And since any reference type is a subtype of `Object`, it should just be:

```
void copyTo2(Object destination, Object source)
```

Generic type parameters in Java are meant to provide constraints so that you can do certain things without casts. However, in this case, you have no bounds on the type parameter, so there is nothing you can depend on being able to do on the type `T` anyway, other than the things available from `Object`.

Comment: The function should copy properties from one instance of another instance of the same class. Kinda like `BeanUtils.copyProperties` but simpler (no conversion necessary) and ignoring null values. Since we want to transfer class specific properties it makes no sense to pass two different types who only have `Object` as common ancestor.

Comment: @Zeeker: But you know nothing about the type of the parameters, so how can you access "properties" unless you use reflection? If you use reflection, there is no type safety anyway. Generics is for type safety, and there is no more type safety that can be gained beyond two parameters of type `Object`. Your requirements are contradictory because "pass two different types who only have Object as common ancestor" *is* passing two things "of the same type" because that type could be `Object`, and any reference type is implicitly convertible to `Object`.

Comment: Jeah, I'm using reflection to access the properties of the Object. Of course we could just copy the properties an `Object` to an `Object`, but what use would that have? I can see and understand the confusion, but by using generics I can at least ensure that the passed parameters don't just have `Object` as common ancestor so copying properties actually makes sense.

Comment: @Zeeker: "but by using generics I can at least ensure that the passed parameters don't just have Object as common ancestor so copying properties actually makes sense." No you can't.

Comment: Ofc I can. With the second version if you pass in a Date object as first parameter you only can pass in second parameter that is a Date itself or a subclass of date, this means that all the Date properties from the second parameter get copied to the first one, no way around that. If I would just allow two arbitrary objects then I could pass String and Date and there wouldn't be any sense in copying.

Comment: @Zeeker: No you can't. This works: `this.<Object, Object>copyTo2(new Date(), "");` So does this: `Object foo = new Date(); copyTo2(foo, "");` The compiler just has crappy inference so that it doesn't figure out the right type arguments to use, but that doesn't mean that it does not work for some choice of type argument.

Comment: Jeah sure, it works if you pass the function explicity objects but as long as the arguments aren't objects but the desired types it will work. I can cast everything into an object and it will work, but this wasn't the point of the question.